# Zend Framework 2 strange behaviour when calling partial view recursively?

Tags: php, zend-framework

I accidentally called a view inside in it self. Like in,

**detail.phtml**

I called

```
<div><?php echo $this->partial('company/company/detail.phtml') ?></div>
```

Which showed a bit strange behavior, I was redirected from http://test.localhost to http://www.test.localhost and server not found error came through. Why is that? What if we need in some situation I need to call views recursively? How can I do it?

Comment: There is double `echo` in your question statement. :-P

Comment: @Bilal sorry that was a type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `detail.phtml`, when you added the line

```
<div><?php echo $this->partial('company/company/detail.phtml') ?></div>
```

Now this line is part of `detail.phtml`. So when this partial loads there is another partial is loading and this process is going into a loop.

So the solution is to change your partial line to

```
<?php if (!isset($renderRecursive)): ?>
     <div><?php echo $this->partial('company/company/detail.phtml', array('renderRecursive' => true) ?></div>
<?php endif;?>
```

This will only loads partial once hence saving us to go into a loop.